# Azure deployment fails with build errors

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-deployment

I have been trying to deploy my web application to azure for two days now. I had finished programming the application and its working properly locally, when i pushed to application to github, and I'm using my student starter plan to deploy it. The application starts deploying then it fails with errors. The errors are below

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2106,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/SchoolManager.Models/SchoolManager.Models.csproj]
Administration/SchoolRole.cs(1,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/SchoolManager.Models/SchoolManager.Models.csproj]
Administration/SchoolUser.cs(1,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/SchoolManager.Models/SchoolManager.Models.csproj]
Tenancy/TenancyRole.cs(1,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/SchoolManager.Models/SchoolManager.Models.csproj]
Tenancy/TenancyUser.cs(2,17): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'AspNetCore' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/SchoolManager.Models/SchoolManager.Models.csproj]
Administration/SchoolRole.cs(5,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityRole<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/SchoolManager.Models/SchoolManager.Models.csproj]
Administration/SchoolUser.cs(7,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/SchoolManager.Models/SchoolManager.Models.csproj]
Tenancy/TenancyRole.cs(5,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityRole<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/SchoolManager.Models/SchoolManager.Models.csproj]
Tenancy/TenancyUser.cs(7,32): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/vsts/work/1/s/SchoolManager.Models/SchoolManager.Models.csproj]
    1 Warning(s)
    8 Error(s)
```

I had even changed the host now to `Azure DevOps` but it still show me the same thing. This has pushed me to rewrite the application from start. It runs locally okay but when i publish it, it fails.

Comment: How are you including the references to the assemblies it's complaining about? Did you drag and drop them locally into your folder, or are you using Nuget references?

Comment: I used the nuget package manager for some and some the visual studio reference suggestion to get the reference. Everything works okay locally but the problem arise when  I push it online

Comment: I have been trying to manipulate the project to see if things work out. I found out that most of those dependencies which are referenced in the project are not in the solution or project folder. They are only in my nuget folder. So why its working locally is that the solutions knows where the nuget folder and references are which it compiles into my bin. But it turns out that when i push the files to github or `Azure DevOps`, only my code is being uploaded. The bin folder is not uploaded since it is not code. How can i make this references show remotely?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. While publishing VS build was failing with - Unable to find dependent project references, but with release version I was able to build the solution.

The fix which worked for me was -
Update VS version to Version 16.7.3.

With this version project build passed successfully and I was able to deploy the packages...in earlier version I think there was a problem with dependency resolver.

Answer (score -2):

When you’re running a web application, you want to be prepared for any issues that may arise, from 500 errors to your users telling you that your site is down. App Service diagnostics is an intelligent and interactive experience to help you troubleshoot your app with no configuration required. If you do run into issues with your app, App Service diagnostics points out what’s wrong to guide you to the right information to more easily and quickly troubleshoot and resolve the issue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-diagnostics